# Intellij idea doesn't give me Create Class intention action if a class name is available to import

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've just started using IntelliJ IDEA and I've noticed something I don't understand.

Given a class:

```
public class Foo {
  public void doStuff() {
    Bar = new Bar();
  }
}
```

This leaves `Bar` undefined with an error message of

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Bar'.

If I open the intention action list (i.e. the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut), I get one of two behaviours:

1. If any classes called `Bar` are available on the classpath then I get options to import them.
2. If no class called `Bar` is on the classpath then I get the option to create it.

In my case, `Bar` is on the classpath but I wanted to create a new one instead. However because the name matches another class on the classpath then I drop into option 1 and never get the option to create it from the intentions list. Is there a way to turn this on or some other shortcut to use?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could untick the "Show import popup for **classes**" option to get rid of that small blue popup that always shows up when there is one unambiguous import (called "import popup").

[image]
[image]
It would turn it off and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for Windows) will open all intention actions available.

[image]

Even if the feature is turned on, you still can access the all-options menu by changing the mouse position (there should be a more convenient way).

Comment: Ah thanks for the info Andrew. I think this explains what I'm seeing, its actually the auto import pop up getting in the way of the intentions actions. I hadn't appreciated how these were interacting and can now see that if I hit the option key once then discard this auto import pop up. I think this answers the questions but would you mind adding a clarification on how auto-import is getting in the way of the intentions actions pop up please? I think it would help others understand faster if they see the same issue and get similarly confused

Comment: @RossPavitt, the import popup just suggests the most expected option to choose. When a popup is shown and you move a mouse, you will be able to access the all-options menu.

Comment: Ah I understand now. It seemed as though it was a keypress change but I can now reproduce with your instructions. Thanks for the help!